# Angular http request executing too late

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular Projekt I have this Code:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    var countTo = 50;
    for (let i = 1; i < (countTo + 1); i++) {
      this.http.get('https://projekt-dunkelbunt.de/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/media?max_page=25&page=' + i).subscribe(data =>{

        for(let key in data){
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
              this.media.push(data[key]);
              console.log(this.media);
              this.descriptions.push(data[key].description.rendered.split('>', 7));
              console.log(this.descriptions);
            }
        }

        console.log("AFTER FOR Length: " + this.media.length);

        if (this.media.length != (this.counter * 10)) {
          this.execute = false;
        }

        this.counter++;

      }, error => {
        console.error("Fehler  beim Laden: " + i + " - " + error);
        i = countTo + 1;
        this.loadPictures();
      });
    }   

    inializeDefaultButtons();

    console.log("ngOnInit(bilder.component.ts) -> done!");
  }
```

My Problem with this Code is, that the for gets executed AFTER the inializeDefaultButtons() and I dont know why, I need the Data from the FOR in the inializeDefaultButtons() Method, but right know the inializeDefaultButtons() Method gets executed and after that the for gets executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I don't know why", simply because it's an asynchronous operation. You ask to do something (like an API call), it takes some time. In the mean time, the code carries on, so the thread isn't blocked. Whenever the API call comes back, the callback function is executed. Welcome to the wonderful world of asynchronism.

Comment: Also you are making 50 simultaneous calls to `projekt-dunkelbunt.de`, not sure the server will like this. You'll probably get banned or denied.

Comment: Is there a way to make the call Synchronously?

Comment: No. And anyway you _really_ don't want to do this. Don't think "Asynchronism is a pain, I want to find a way to do things synchronously". Worse mistake ever, because you will be blocking your threrad and freezing your site and your server. Learn and embrace asynchronism.

Comment: Yeah but First I need to get the Data and when I have the Data i need to do something with it. In my Asynchronous Code, its doing something with the data ander then gettnig the data, there is something wrong i guess

Comment: I have marked your question as a duplicate (as not understanding asynchronism is a very, very, VERY, VEEEEERRRRYYYYY common question), please visit the link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javasript has a well known [asynchrounous behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing).
Try to put your `inializeDefaultButtons()` inside your subscribe first callback (right after your `for .. in` loop ) and it will be invoked when the loop is done.

```
 this.http.get('https://projekt-dunkelbunt.de/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/media?max_page=25&page=' + i).subscribe(data =>{

        for(let key in data){
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
              this.media.push(data[key]);
              console.log(this.media);
              this.descriptions.push(data[key].description.rendered.split('>', 7));
              console.log(this.descriptions);
            }
        }

        console.log("AFTER FOR Length: " + this.media.length);

        inializeDefaultButtons(); // <-- here


        if (this.media.length != (this.counter * 10)) {
          this.execute = false;
        }

        this.counter++;

      }, error => {
        console.error("Fehler  beim Laden: " + i + " - " + error);
        i = countTo + 1;
        this.loadPictures();
      });
    }
```

The reason is that JS merely doesn't wait the end of execution for an unknown *time-to-execute* event (Http response in your case), so it makes your implemented code in stand-by, till a response is retrieved from the backend service, at this stage, it gets back to the code-to-exectue inside the `data`'s callback and start its execution.

Comment: Higher order operators would make things really clean in this scenario, It's sad to see OP is not utilising wonderful features provided by RXJS 
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293

Comment: @Vikas Agree, seems he/she's new to JS. Introducing such terms in an early stage could mess it up IMHO. Thanks tho

Comment: Agree with u too :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve ?

You can create observables without subscribing to them for each and then binding all obserevable into concat operator if their order is to be kept.

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat

Comment: Getting Data from the FOR and doing something with the Data in the method call